# ¿Por qué caí en un ciclo infinito?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un programa que calcule la mediana y aún no la tengo completa porque voy paso a paso, pero en una parte caí en un ciclo infinito al parecer y no se el porqué. Ya estuve revisando un buen rato mi código y sigo sin ver cuál es el error.

```
function calcularMediana(lista){
    lista.sort(); //[2, 24, 35, 74, 867]
    while(lista.length > 2){
        if(bandera === 0){
            lista.shift();
            bandera = 1;
        } else if(bandera === 1){
            lista.pop();
            bandera = 0;
        }      
    }
}

var lista1 = [35, 74, 24, 867, 2];
calcularMediana(lista1);

var mediana;

var bandera = 0;
```

Comment: Pon la bandera justo antes  del while, es decir, dentro de la función agrega la línea `var bandera = 0;` y por otro lado cambia el `>2` por `>=2`. Con eso ya te funcionará pero creo que estás siendo super ineficiente. ¿Ir sacando elementos uno por uno? ¿En serio? ¿No es más fácil ordenar la lista e indexarla en .length/2?

Comment: Cuando llamas a la función `calcularMediana`, `bandera` todavía ni siquiera existe (es `undefined`), por lo que nunca se evaluarán los condicionales dentro del `while` ya que `undefined` ni es 0 ni es 1. Como no se evalúan los condicionales, pues nunca se saca ningún elemento del arreglo. Como nunca se saca nada, lista siempre tendrá un tamaño mayor que 2, por tanto, nunca saldrás del ciclo.

Comment: Socio disculpa que intervenga pero así no se calcula la mediana

Comment: @Japv Tu comentario sobraba ante todo y ya encontre una forma de sacar la mediana (solo que no funciona cuando es par)

function calcularMediana(lista){
    lista.sort();
    if(!lista.length % 2 === 0){ //Array impar
        while(lista.length >= 2){
            lista.shift();
            lista.pop();
        }
        mediana = lista[0]; 
    }     
}
    

var mediana; 
var lista1 = [5, 3, 6, 3, 8, 2, 8];
var bandera = 0;
calcularMediana(lista1);

Existen muchas maneras de llegar a una solucion y la mia fue esa, y pues tampoco es que haya utilizado tantas lineas.

Comment: @Japv asi que evitese esos comentarios (era completamente innecesario).

Comment: @Edson no te pongas bravo, simplemente te hice una observacion valida, debes ser un poco mas receptivo, aunque no lo creas si en un examen das esa solucion suspendes, asi que no te me molestes por gusto y mira el lado positivo aprendiste algo nuevo, y si tienes dudas me dices que con gusto te ayudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí te dejo mi propuesta para obtener la mediana de una lista.

Para calcular la mediana debes tener en cuenta que si la longitud de la lista es impar el cálculo sería:

```
Me = (n + 1) / 2
```

Donde **n** es la longitud de la lista, por tanto la mediana en este caso estaría justo en el centro de la lista.

Por otra parte si la longitud de la lista es par la mediana sería la media aritmética de los dos valores centrales de la lista, y las posiciones que ocuparían  estos valores centrales serian **n / 2** y **(n / 2) + 1**, siendo **n** la longitud de la lista, por tanto el cálculo sería:

```
Me = (X(n / 2) + X((n / 2) + 1)) / 2
```

Por tanto tu algoritmo final quedaría:

```
function CalcularMediana(lista)
{
   var mediana = 0;
   var indice = 0;
   var longitud = lista.length;

   lista.sort();

   if (longitud % 2 === 1)
   {
      indice = (longitud + 1) / 2;
      mediana = lista[indice]; 
   }
   else
   {
      indice = (longitud / 2);
      mediana = (lista[indice] + lista[indice + 1]) / 2;
   }

   return mediana[indice];
}
```

Aquí se declaran tres variables:

**mediana**: Se guarda el cálculo de la mediana de la lista pasada como parámetro.

**indice**: Se guarda la posición central de la lista pasada como parámetro.

**longitud**: Se guarda la longitud de la lista pasada como parámetro.

Posteriormente se ordena la lista y se pregunta si la longitud de la lista es par o impar, atendiendo al valor que devuelve la evaluación de esta condición se obtendría la mediana aplicando lo primero que se explicó en dependencia de si la longitud de la lista es par o impar. Por último se devuelve la mediana obtenida.

Comment: Muy buena solución. Esa es la manera más óptima . La manera en que se proponía en la pregunta era sumamente ineficiente, y como bien dices, para un array con una longitud par no daba la mediana.